# Entering automatic PiP triggers onPause on Android 13 but not Android 12

Tags: android

If I use gesture navigations on Android 12 and 13 and I pull up from the bottom, which takes me to the Android home screen, on Android 12 I don't get an `onPause` event and on Android 13 I do.

I already have `android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"` on my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I don't have much of a problem with `onPause` being called, it is just that I haven't found a way to detect that this `onPause` is being called because it is entering PiP.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: `onPause` is triggered before `onPictureInPictureModeChanged` so it is difficult to do logic at that point without knowing if the app is going into PiP mode or not.

Edit: Bug report https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/258154758

Comment: Using `onPictureInPictureModeChanged()` you should be able to detect when when app goes or comes in pip mode. (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture#handling_ui). What are you trying to detect/change in `onPause`?

Comment: I'm trying to add support for background play without picture in picture so I need to be able to know if the app is going on the background for picture in picture or not. The issue with `onPictureInPictureModeChanged()` is that it seems to trigger after `onPause()` so on the `onPause()` method when I have to check that, I don't know that the app is going to PiP mode.